# PHP recursive function returns incorrect array of hierarchical SQL table data

Tags: php, sql, recursion

I have hierarchical data in SQL table like this

```
ID         NAME                        PARENT_ID 
1         Sales                             
2         Marketing                      1
3         sales_optimiztaion.txt         2
4         Quotes                         6
5         list.xls                       4
6         General data
```

This is folder structure, we can get path to each file, for example, if we have file `list.xls` then its parent folders are `Quotes` and `General data -> General data/Quotes/list.xls`

I have recursive function that returns all parents of each file and return array of them

```
function get_pathS($node) { 

$resultS = mysql_query('SELECT NAME, PARENT_ID FROM b_disk_object  
                       WHERE ID="'.$node.'";'); 
      $rowS = mysql_fetch_array($resultS);

      if ($rowS['NAME']!='') {

        $path=$rowS['NAME'];
                $content=array();
                $content[]=$path;

            get_pathS($rowS['PARENT_ID']);
    }

 return $content;
}
```

It works correctly and saves all parents of each file in array, but when I call this function, it only returns first parent of each file.

Here is function call

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

$folder= get_pathS($row['PARENT_ID']);

foreach($folder as $f){
echo $f.'<br>';
....
```

It echos only first parent, like this

```
Marketing 

Quotes
```

instead of this

```
Marketing

Sales

Quotes

General data
```

Comment: when you call `get_pathS($rowS['PARENT_ID']);` inside `get_pathS()`, you don't catch its return value... you should merge your current `$content` with it.

Comment: When i check the function, by adding foreach($content as $f){echo $f;}  before return, it echos all parents correctly

Comment: yes, because you call the good number of times `get_pathS()`, you just don't store the result... So you have 3 different arrays, each with only 1 folder name. and you only return the first one...

Comment: Thank you very much for hint, I solved my problem! Just passed $content array as argument to get_pathS function instead of declaring it inside of it.

Comment: That works too. Note the better practice would be doing an array merge with the returned value...